# removing two GET parameters from url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, get

I have a url that looks like this

http://example.com/index.php**?con=something&met=meh**

What i'm trying to do is get rid of `con=` and `met=` so the url would look like

http://example.com/index.php**/something/meh**

That's what i've done so far

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but nothing changes, the url it still look the same http://example.com/index.php**?con=something&met=meh**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?con=$1&met=$2` much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /index.php?con=$1&meh=$2 [NC]
```

Notice that if you don't pass any meh, it still works.

Comment: it works without the `/` in `/index.php?con=$1&meh=$2` thanks